# Getting Users Details back from Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to flutter and firebase and am really struggling.
I have been trying for about 2 weeks to work this out but I can't for the life of me work out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to retrieve the 'DisplayName' from a 'users' collection with UID Document and DisplayName.
When I use The MyUser in other widgets using the provider package the DisplayName displays null, the console displays ' not again' so it appears that it's just not working at this point.(code below)

I have researched and I can't seem to find any why this code works. I am a NOOB so it may be something simple and after 2 weeks I thought I would ask for help.

Thanks In advance anything I can learn would be great.

```
Stream<List<MyUser>> get user {
    var user = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    return user.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs
        .map((doc) => MyUser(
              displayName: doc['DisplayName'] ?? 'not again',
            ))
        .toList());
  }
```

Comment: Since we can't see your source data to understand what this code should be producing, and we can't see if your query is generating any errors, there's not much we can do to help.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.